# Pivot table from quiz answers in excel

Tags: excel

I have quiz plugin in wordpress from which i can export results in excel.

Excel structure:

https://prnt.sc/9V1QZlzYalDa

How can i for example get how many incorrect answers are there for question 1?

Answer (score 2):

The command, `countif`, may be helpful for your case. Here is [a link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34) to the corresponding docs.

You would use it as follows to count the number of incorrect questions for question 1 (where E2 to E4 is the range within which the occurrences of "Incorrect" are counted):

```
=countif(E2:E4,"Incorrect")
```